# onclick handler not firing for checkbox created with document.createElement

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

I am going insane trying to figure out why this is not working. I am creating a checkbox dynamically with JS to enable/disable a text field (also created dynamically).

Code is pretty simple:

```
var text = $(document.createElement("input"));
text.type = "text";
container.appendChild(text);

...

var check = $(document.createElement("input"));
check.type = "checkbox";
check.onclick = function(event) {
    if (this.checked) text.enable();
    else text.disable();
};
container.appendChild(check);
```

I've tried putting the event handler after `container.appendChild(check);`, but that yields the same result.

There are no JS errors, and results are the same in Chrome, FF3.6, and IE7.

Can anyone explain why this isn't working? Any fixes would be appreciated.

Strangely (because theoretically it should be the same as above), adding the following (after `container.appendChild(check);`) works (checkbox is first on page):

```
$$("input[type=checkbox]")[0].onclick = function(event) {
    if (this.checked) text.enable();
    else text.disable();
};
```

I don't really like this, as it seems "dirty", and the checkbox may not be the first on the page later on...

BTW, $ and $$ are from Prototype.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When I inspect the checkbox with Chrome (and FF), it says it has no event listeners. Perhaps this helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the problem...

After all of this code, I was adding some text by appending to innerHTML of `container`. For some reason, this threw off all of the event handlers for that container.

Using `container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("..."));` fixed the problem.

Hope this helps anyone else who might be having this sort of problem...

Comment: Aha! More context was needed :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that appending directly to innerHTML could interfere with it... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have any errors?

`craeteElement` is misspelled in the first line. After fixing that, it all works on my machine with 1.6.1 and 1.7RC1.

http://jsfiddle.net/4XWP3/

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault (typing error). It's spelled correctly in my code, and doesn't work...

Comment: does the link I posted work for you? if not, can you post a reproducible example of it on http://jsfiddle.net or somewhere else

Comment: Yeah, the link works. But strangely, my code still doesn't work.

Comment: what version of Prototype? If the versions match too (1.6.1.0 or 1.7RC1), then something else in your code is breaking it.

Comment: I'm using 1.6.1.0 right now. I'll try to look for something else that could be causing a conflict...

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Prototype is doing nothing for you here, so I'd suggest dropping it. The following works and simplifies things:

```
var text = document.createElement("input");
text.type = "text";
container.appendChild(text);

...

var check = document.createElement("input");
check.type = "checkbox";
check.onclick = function(event) {
    text.disabled = !this.checked;
};
container.appendChild(check);
```

Comment: Using $(...) wrappers for IE, to have Prototype methods tacked onto the new objects.

Comment: The problem isn't that the handler doesn't work, it's that the handler doesn't even get fired. I can put an alert("") in there and click the checkbox and nothing happens.

That's probably more efficient that what I had, so I'll probably use that...

Comment: The handler fires for me when I use `document.body` as the container, so there must be some other issue. Perhaps you could give more context?

Comment: container is really a div that's also dynamically created (and added to document.body). But I tried that on jsFiddle and it worked too. There's really not much more context than that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the `$(...)` wrappers?  Why not:

```
var text = document.createElement("input");
text.type = "text";
container.appendChild(text);
...
var check = document.createElement("input");
check.type = "checkbox";
check.onclick = function(event) {
    if (check.checked) text.enable();
    else text.disable();
};
container.appendChild(check);
```

Also, note that I changed `if (this.checked)` to `if (check.checked)` since `this` can get crazy in JS.

Comment: No need to change `this` to `check`: in this instance, `this` is guaranteed to be a reference to the checkbox. It's more useful to understand fully the rules about `this` than to avoid it entirely.

Comment: Using $(...) wrappers for IE, to have Prototype methods tacked onto the new objects.

Tried both this. and check. but same results. I prefer using check. anyway, had it as this. from pasting out of HTML attribute...